# React redux store state management

Tags: redux, state, store

Why react redux store state lost when page reload or refresh?

Please explain in detail is it obvious or should it persistent across the global applications

Answer (score 1):

That's normal JavaScript behavior.  A Redux store is just a normal JS variable, and all JS values are thrown away when a page is refreshed.

You can manually persist data from the Redux store using something like `localStorage`, but you have to specifically choose to do so.

Comment: Then why redux comes into react, if we choose localStorage to store our states?